# How can I run Windows Check Disk without being Prompted?

Tags: windows-7, check-disk

The Windows 7 backup tool is telling me I have a bad index.  How can I run Checkdisk without being prompted at boot?

Comment: @Moab are you saying I can't?  If so, then what is the answer about below?  Also, is there a way to manually enter/restart into Windows Recovery Environment?

Comment: @Moab can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you select 'Automatically fix file system errors' for a disk that is in use (for example, the partition that contains Windows), you'll be prompted to reschedule the disk check for the next time you restart your computer. It cannot repair on the fly.

If you want to check your hard disk without restarting:

- Click to open Computer.
- Right-click the hard disk that you want to check, and then click Properties.
- Click the Tools tab, and then, under Error-checking, click Check now.  If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

  [image: image of Properties of disc]
- To automatically repair problems with files and folders that the scan detects, select "Automatically fix file system errors." Otherwise, the disk check will report problems but not fix them.
- To perform a thorough disk check, select Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors. This scan attempts to find and repair physical errors on the hard disk itself, and it can take much longer to complete.
- To check for both file errors and physical errors, select both "Automatically fix file system errors" and "Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors."
- Click "Start."

  (This can take a while).

  [image: image of check disk prompt]

  You can check for bad sectors without prompt, but it can not repair while Windows is in use.

Answer (score 2):

Chkdsk cannot fix any file system or Sector errors while in Windows, either schedule a chkdsk on restart or use Windows RE and the command prompt to run chkdsk.

How to use WinRE, restart the PC, use F8 repeatedly to get the Windows Advanced screen, then choose "Repair Your computer", this will load WinRE, if you get a message about RE finding some errors and wants to repair, say NO, let RE continue to load, when it loads choose "repair your computer" again, then choose Command prompt from the list of Tools and run this command

> chkdsk /r C:

.
[image]

.
[image]

.