# Use a Win 7 Ultimate CD to repair Win 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, repair, chkdsk

I am suspecting my Win 7 Home has some hard drive issue, probably bad index. According to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/336700/how-can-i-run-windows-check-disk-without-being-prompted), I was wondering if it's possible to use a Win 7 Ultimate CD to repair Win 7 Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, more-so if it's a startup issue.  But the install DVD has to be matching your system in bit-version.  ie, 32-bit vs 64-bit.
There's no harm in trying.  If the disk sees the installation upon Repair, go for it.